# Focus placed on parent folder name after adding new folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Any time I add a new folder in Visual Studio 2015 it highlights the parent folder name instead of the new folder. This is insanely annoying because I end up renaming the parent instead of the new folder all the time. See screenshot for example. I added a new folder to the project WebApplication1. Instead of highlighting the new folder (NewFolder1) that I just created, it highlights the parent. Does anyone know of a setting that might be causing this?

[image]

**EDIT**

The issue appears to be linked to the Funnel (vsFunnel) plug-in. If I disable that plug-in then the issue goes away. I've tried adjusting various settings for this plug-in without any positive result. Any solutions, outside of "disable that plug-in", would be useful.

Comment: Can /safemode save you?

Comment: That is not how Project > New Folder behaves, it selects the added folder and lets you instantly type a new name.  I suspect you'll have to tame your add-ins.

Comment: @qxg - Using /SafeMode did quell the issue. I assume this means that there might be an extension that is wreaking havoc on my IDE. I guess I'll have to sort determine which one is causing this behavior.

Comment: @Hans Passant - I know _how_ New Folder is supposed to work; that is why I posted the question. And yes, after running in SafeMode, at qxg's suggestion, I will be narrowing my focus to the extensions.

Comment: @HansPassant - Please provide an official answer so I can award the bounty. Thanks.

Comment: @qxg - Please provide an official answer so I can award the bounty. Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to make your question useful first.  You know it is an add-in so list the add-ins you have installed.  No doubt somebody will show up and mention "Ah, yes, that bag 'o bugs screwed me up as well, just uninstall it and use *this* one instead".